# Why is QSslSocket not emitting `readyRead()` signal when connecting from "BrowserStack" mobiles?

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, browserstack, qsslsocket

We are using `QSslServer` to accept https connections in form of `QSslSocket`s and it's working for years in Windows, Mac, Ubuntu & Android's Chrome & Firefox.

To our surprise, the website connection is not happening if we use [**Browserstack**](https://www.browserstack.com/)'s mobiles, which are supposedly not emulators. Our URL looks like: https://website.in: **2000**; So it's not on port 443 or 80.
The web page doesn't open with Android 9, 10, 11, 12's Chromes.

No errors are seen with `sslErrors()`. Even calling `ignoreSslErrors()` didn't help.
After putting logs, we found that though the connection is happening, the `QSslSocket::readyRead()` is not emitted, which is called with our normal devices.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Following are creating the issues:

- URL with **non-standard port**. We are using :2000 to host our website and that's not working for SSL authentication after initial connection. If we route our website through :443 then it starts working.
- **LetsEncrypt** certificate. We had faced some issue in Mac in past, where the certificate generated using "LetsEncrypt.org" had to be explicitly accepted from Mac's certificate store. Here the similar issue is happening. After opening the website, certain images don't show up probably due to the same reasons.